# How to change Azure Analysis Services project from readonly to read-write?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-analysis-services

I downloaded the deployed model from Azure Portal and I was trying to modify some measures and redeploy the solution. Everything is greyed out and I can change nothing, even when I want to save the model I get the following error (see picture below):
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHOg7.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/189053/i-can39t-update-my-azure-analysis-services-model.html) as per the original poster on the Microsoft Q&A platform.

> The problem was fixed by itself I kept closing and reopening Visual Studio until it allowed me to process the cube and re allowed me to modify my measures.